# Does C++ vector copy constructor and assignment operator also copies reserved space?

Tags: c++

Copy constructor is called

```
vector<int> v0;
v0.reserve(3);
vector<int> v1 = v0;
```

Will v1 also has reserved space of 3?

Assignment operator is called

```
vector<int> v0;
v0.reserve(3);
vector<int> v1;
v1 = v0;
```

Will v1 also has reserved space of 3?

Comment: `v0` contains three zeroes, of course they are copied. You don't call `.reserve()` anywhere, so I'm not sure why you talk about "reserved space".

Comment: You could've tested this yourself easily.

Comment: With the possible exception of the capacity, `v1` should be an exact copy of `v0` in both cases. `v0 == v1` and `v0.size() == v1.size()` should both be true.

Comment: No: https://godbolt.org/z/VPMZmW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standart doesn't tell anything about additional reservation after copying.
So, reserved space is realization specific. So, you shouldn't rely on reserved space after copy.

Answer (score 2):

Standard does not say anything regarding this: http://eel.is/c++draft/vector

It is implementation-specific.

`clang`, for example, does not check how much capacity is reserved in the initial vector and just allocates according to the number of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can convince yourself by a small example

```
std::vector<int> x(10);
x.reserve(20);
std::vector<int> y;
y = x;
std::cout << y.capacity();
```

output is `10` in my case.

Also consider that in general the effect of `y = x` is that afterwards `(y == x) == true`, and `==` does not take into account reserved space:

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::vector<int> y;
x.reserve(10);
y.reserve(20);
std::cout << (x == y);
```

output

```
1
```

Further consider that `std::vector::operator==` has complexity ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)):

> 1) Linear in the size of *this and other.

If after assignment `y` would have same capacity as `x`, `operator==`s complexity would depend on the capacity not just the size.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard specifies that for containers, making a copy requires that `std::equal(src.begin(), src.end(), copy.begin(), copy.end())` is true afterwards. Vector containers do not have additional requirements, so `src.capacity()` and `copy.capacity()` are unrelated.

We can deduce some additional, implicit requirements. E.g. that `src.end()-src.begin() == copy.end()-copy.begin()` else `std::equal` would return false, and therefore also `src.size()==copy.size()` But all of them relate to the elements of the vector, not the capacity.